# textbox not being reset despite the fact that property to which it is bound being set to null

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a textbox on a form whose text property is not being reset despite the fact that the string property to which it is bound being set to null.  Access is controlled by another checkbox, called cbxPartIINA, on the form.  When the cbxPartIINA is checked the textbox is supposed to be disabled and blanked out. When I check cbxPartIINA, the textbox is disabled, but not blanked.

Here is the XAML for the textbox:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxLength="25" 
                        MinWidth="200" CharacterCasing="Upper" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource PartIIGridIsEnabledTextBox}"
                        Margin="5,2,0,3" FontWeight="Bold" Name="tbxNewSuspectLastName" 
                        Text="{Binding Form104CModel.NewSuspectLastName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here is the static resource:

```
       <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="PartIIGridIsEnabledTextBox">
            <!-- This style is used to turn off TextBoxes in Part II-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbxPartIINA}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbxPartIINA}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

Here is the XAML for the checkbox that, when checked, turns off the textbox:

```
 <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Content="NA" Background="White" Height="20" Width="auto" BorderBrush="Black" Name="cbxPartIINA" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=Form104CModel.IsPartIINA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And here's the property to which the textbox.text is bound:

```
    private String newsuspectlastname;
    public String NewSuspectLastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsuspectlastname;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsuspectlastname = value;
            this.NewSuspect.LastName = value;
        }
    }
```

The textbox.text property is not being reset despite the fact that the binding is two-way and the underlying property, NewSuspectLastName, is being set to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF uses INotifyPropertyChanged to monitory changes in the underlying model.

You need to implement INotofyPropertyChanged on on your model like this:

```
public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged  
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.  
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName  
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.  
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
    {  
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }  

    private String newsuspectlastname;
    public String NewSuspectLastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsuspectlastname;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.newsuspectlastname )  
             {  
                 this.newsuspectlastname = value;
                 this.NewSuspect.LastName = value;
                 NotifyPropertyChanged();  
            }  

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: INotifyProperty changed is implemented in a class from which my model inherits, so that means it's already implemented, by inheritance, in my model.  But thanks for your answer.   The problem is fixed.  The problem was that I was setting the binding of the text property at the object, and then trying to reset it in the style.  Being somewhat new to WPF, I didn't know that.  What was really throwing me off was that the technique was working for the IsEnabled property and and ComboBoxes.

Comment: Well the code you posted is NOT using INotifyPropertyChanged.  You NEED to fire the event whenever the property changes.  And your code does not do that

Comment: In other words every single property setter HAS to fire the PropertyChange event. Otherwise the WPF engine never knows the property has changed

Comment: Thanks.  That last part is something I'm going to have to remember.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you set the Text binding at the Object level and not the Style level. Setting the property directly on the object will always prevail over the value set by the Style. In order to achieve what you need, you simply need to move your binding to the style, like so :

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="PartIIGridIsEnabledTextBox">
    <!-- This style is used to turn off TextBoxes in Part II-->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbxPartIINA}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=cbxPartIINA}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value=""/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Form104CModel.NewSuspectLastName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>
```

And your TextBox will look like this :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxLength="25" MinWidth="200" CharacterCasing="Upper" BorderThickness="0" Style="{StaticResource PartIIGridIsEnabledTextBox}" Margin="5,2,0,3" FontWeight="Bold" Name="tbxNewSuspectLastName"/>
```

Comment: I can't set the binding at the style level, as multiple textboxes use this style, thus they would all be bound to the same property.   I'll try it, but I'll have to change the Key so that only my last name textbox uses that style.  I've even tried setting the NewSuspectLastName property to null when the property IsPartIINA was set to true (it's a Boolean), figuring that the two-way binding to the textbox would kick in, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Thanks.  You helped fix it.  I simply set the style at the object level, and moved the binding into the style at the object level.  I guess using a static resource has its limits.

Comment: Glad I could help!